# How to disable webkit-text-size-adjust with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension that will automatically disable the webkit-text-size-adjust CSS rule on LinkedIn.  This is so I can get the text to zoom when I zoom on the page.

Using Chrome's developer tools in the Elements Styles window, I can change the webkit-text-size-adjust from "none" to "0", and this lets the text change size when I zoom.

However, I can't figure out how to disable this rule with JavaScript.  I have written a Chrome extension that executes a function when I visit linkedin.com/* but I need to write a function to remove/modify the webkit-text-size-adjust rule.

I've tried a few things, but they don't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust="0"
```

I've also tried recursively going through each childNode from document.body and using removeProperty to turn it off, but this doesn't work for me either.

```
function remtextadj(node){
  node.style.removeProperty('-webkit-text-size-adjust');
  for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;i++){
     var nod=node.childNodes[i];
     remtextadj(nod);
     }
  }

  remtextadj(document.body);
```

So how could I go about removing this rule with javascript?  I'm no expert on CSS or JavaScript, so I imagine I'm missing something simple...

Comment: I have poor eye site and constantly have my pages at 200% default zoom. With -webkit-text-size-adjust:none, I cannot read anything, and my only alternative is to use Firefox. It's my number one problem these days when browsing. Please please please fix this and share with me the link.

Comment: As I couldn't see anyone actually having packaged this up, I did.  Entirely stolen from comments here, bar having to use "auto" for the value: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webkit-text-size-adjust-r/jgfjnnljbpgajihjcajeiabjomhmjhec

Comment: Many thanks for creating the extension, really useful!  The careless use of -webkit-text-size-adjust:none by many sites may be the reason Chrome market share has started to decline.

Comment: @FauxFaux I was just starting to get pissed off with sites doing this, I had been manually changing font sizes on a few sites and decided I'd had enough, will find what's causing it and write an extension, thanks for saving me some effort :)

Comment: It appears `element.style.webkitTextSizeAdjust` isn't a Javascript property; you annoyingly have to address it using `element.style["-webkit-text-size-adjust"]`. Apologies for this late comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the following CSS, which should force the browser to use the style:

```
*{-webkit-text-size-adjust:0 !important}
```

The `!important` flag causes the declaration to take the highest available precedence.  Add the custom styles to a page via the `manifest` file:

```
 ...
 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://sitehere/*"],
    "css": ["customstyle.css"]
 }],
 ...
```

Comment: I want to disable font-adjust for ALL sites. How do I do that?

Comment: @Theodore Use `<all_URLs>` or `*://*/*` in the matches field plus an `!important` flag

Answer (score 2):

```
var myStyle = document.createElement('style');
myStyle.innerHTML = 'body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;}';
document.head.appendChild(myStyle);
```